# Spring Session without Redis

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-websocket, spring-session

I wanted to try Spring Session integration in order to link Websocket session with http session. But I am not ready to go full Radis/Hazlecast yet. My server uses Tomcat replication. What will having just MapSessionRepository do? Tomcat doesn't seem to be able to replicate this session.

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
...
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
   return new Filter[] { new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSessionRepositoryFilter")};
}
...
@Bean
public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository( ) {
    return new MapSessionRepository();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating `MapSessionRepository` using default constructor will use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to store the sessions. This means that session storage is local to your current JVM.

Such configuration can be useful for development/testing purposes but it does not take advantage of Spring Session's ability to store sessions outside of JVM which is one of the key features.

Regarding Tomcat replication, note that the core concept of Spring Session is to store sessions in a container neutral way.

Comment: `MapSessionRepository` doesn't support eviction of stale sessions...